# How to save name of the recognized face from face recognition program after the face is recognised?

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-recognition

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat imgRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat img = new Mat();
    imgRgba.copyTo(img);
    List<Mat> images = ppF.getProcessedImage(img, PreProcessorFactory.PreprocessingMode.RECOGNITION);
    Rect[] faces = ppF.getFacesForRecognition();

    // Selfie / Mirror mode
    if(front_camera){
        Core.flip(imgRgba,imgRgba,1);
    }
    if(images == null || images.size() == 0 || faces == null || faces.length == 0 || ! (images.size() == faces.length)){

        return imgRgba;
    } else {
        faces = MatOperation.rotateFaces(imgRgba, faces, ppF.getAngleForRecognition());
        for(int i = 0; i<faces.length; i++){
            MatOperation.drawRectangleAndLabelOnPreview(imgRgba, faces[i], rec.recognize(images.get(i),""), front_camera);
          
 //Here "rec.recognize(images.get(i)" have name but i'm unable to print..

        }

        return imgRgba;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Qualeams/Android-Face-Recognition-with-Deep-Learning-Test-Framework